# Facet on multiple fields at once and aggregate the results

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I have a couple fields that represent error codes, they take the form error_code1, error_code2 ... error_code5.

Is there a way to facet across all of them so that I can get a count of error codes across all of the error code fields?

If one doc has error_code1 = 42 and another has error_code3 = 42, I want to get a count of 2 for error code 42

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried facet.field=error_code1&facet.field=error_code2, etc.... ?

Comment: Yeah - but then I have to aggregate the data myself on the client side. Which I can do but was trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an aggregating field `all_errors` and use `<copyField source="error_code*" dest="all_errors" />` to populate it.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I can't change the schema, but I like the idea

Comment: I ended up just making a multivalued field and populating it when I load the data since I couldn't change the schema, but this was the right idea